# React JS TypeError: selectedWord.split is not a function

Tags: reactjs, function

I am working on the Hangman game using react js, came across the error "TypeError: selectedWord.split is not a function" below is the code:

```
const Word = (selectedWord, correctLetters) => {
return (
    <div className='word' id='word'>
      {selectedWord.split().map((letter, i) =>{
           return(
            <span className='letter' key={i}>
            ${correctLetters.includes(letter)? letter : ''}
        </span>
           );
        
        })}  
    </div>
   );
  }
```

Comment: I think you meant to write `({ selectedWord, correctLetters })` (with curly braces)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you are destructuring the props is incorrect, the correct syntax is:

```
const Word = ({ selectedWord, correctLetters }) => {
  ...
}
```

In your code, all of the props end up in the `selectedWord` variable.